# How to receive one in app notification per user following you?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently finished implementing an in-app notification, albeit there is a huge flaw to the implementation. As much as it is quite feasible when sending an activation message to all users having successfully activated their account it gets a bit complicated when one user follows an end user. When the current user follows and unfollows a few times,  the end user gets multiple notifications from the current user. How does one destroy a notification when the current user unfollows the end user, to stop sending multiple "current user started following you" notifications to the end user?

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick word_start: [:name, :surname] 

  has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id 

...

  # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    following << other_user
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    following.delete(other_user)
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

...
```

Relationship model

```
 class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    validates  :follower_id, presence: true
    validates  :followed_id, presence: true

 end
```

Notification Model

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :actor, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  scope :unread, ->{ where(read_at: nil) }
  scope :recent, ->{ order(created_at: :desc).limit(5) }

end
```

Relationship Controller

```
 class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :logged_in_user

  def create 
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)  
    Notification.create(recipient: @user, actor: current_user, action: "following", notifiable: @user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    # Where the notification should be destroyed
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you implemented your relationship model.

I would only send an email when a relation is created. If a user unfollows another user I would not delete that relation, but flag it as unfollowed. If the user decides to follow the same user again, then you just need to remove the flag that marks the relation as non-active. That means you do not create a new relation, therefore you do not need to send an email.

First, you will need to add an `active` boolean flag to your `Relationship` model. That can be done with a migration like this:

```
def change 
  add_column :relationships, :active, :boolean, default: true
end
```

Then you need to respect the `active` flag in your associations and scopes:

```
has_many :following, 
  -> { Relationship.where(active: true) },
  through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
has_many :followers, 
  -> { Relationship.where(active: true) },
  through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

Next, change the `follow` and `unfollow` methods:

```
def follow(other_user)
  relationship = Relationship.where(
    followed_id: other_user.id, follower_id: self.id
  ).first

  if relationship.present?
    relationship.update(active: true) 
  else
    following << other_user

    Notification.create(
      action:     'following', 
      actor:      self, 
      notifiable: other_user,
      recipient:  other_user
    )
  end
end

def unfollow(other_user)
  relationship = Relationship.where(
    followed_id: other_user.id, follower_id: self.id
  )

  relationship.update(active: false) if relationship.present?
end

def following?(other_user)
  Relationship.exists?(
    followed_id: other_user.id, follower_id: self.id, active: true   
  )
end
```

Note that the `Notification` is created in the `follow` method now. That allows to simplify the controller:

```
def create 
  @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
  current_user.follow(@user)  

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow(@user)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: that is sound advice but how do I change my user model from
`def unfollow(other_user)
   following.delete(other_user)
end`

Comment: Please show your `User` model especially the `follow` and `unfollow` methods.

Comment: I have been thinking about this problem since I had to it face again recently.

The `following?` predicate method changed, please look into `user.rb`.

Comment: One last surmountable hurdle. How do you update the count of all the users your following for a situation where `current_user` follows and unfollows the `other_user`. The record of the following will still be stored in the database since technically the relationship is not destroyed. So using the `count` method will not suffice in this case.

Comment: Just count the number of `following`: `user.following.count`. The `folllowing` relation is already scoped to `where(active: true)` and should not include `active_relationships` that are `active != true`.

Comment: That makes sense and I have tried it. Well I guess in this case the scope is not being respected when `other_user` is being unfollowed since the count only goes up and never decrements.